# FB.Init() is not accepting in my c# Script

Tags: c#, unity, facebook

I am trying to connect fb with my game. its first time i am connecting fb with game. i downloaded fb SDk  7.3.0 and i am using unity 5.2.1f1. i imported the sdk in my game asset. then i created a new c# script "FBholder". in Awake() i tried to use FB.Init(). but its not accepting. all other scripts used inside the game are calling correctly, only the scripts came with fb sdk is not working.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

public class Fbholder : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Awake() {
    FB.Init (SetInit, OnHideUnity);// This line is not accepting
}
}
```

i Used this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmeMHY5D4SI) for my referance

Comment: any error or logs?

Comment: yes, The name `FB' does not exist in the current context

Comment: but it exist in my project, If i tried to create another c# script as Fb means it displays an error message as " The nameSpace already exist'

Comment: check the edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not included the correct namespace for `FB`.

Write `using Facebook.Unity;` at top of your class.

Here is the sample script for using `Facebook` with common features, such as posting score, with latest SDK.

```
using Facebook.Unity;

List<string> perms = new List<string> (){"public_profile", "email", "user_friends"};

void Awake ()
    {
        if (!FB.IsInitialized) {
            // Initialize the Facebook SDK
            FB.Init (InitCallback, OnHideUnity);
        } else {
            // Already initialized, signal an app activation App Event
            FB.ActivateApp ();
        }
    }

private void InitCallback ()
    {
        if (FB.IsInitialized) {
            // Signal an app activation App Event
            FB.ActivateApp ();
            // Continue with Facebook SDK
            // ...
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Failed to Initialize the Facebook SDK");
        }
    }

    private void OnHideUnity (bool isGameShown)
    {
        if (!isGameShown) {
            // Pause the game - we will need to hide
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        } else {
            // Resume the game - we're getting focus again
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result)
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            // AccessToken class will have session details
            var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            // Print current access token's User ID
            Debug.Log (aToken.UserId);
            // Print current access token's granted permissions
            foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) {
                Debug.Log (perm);
            }
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("User cancelled login");
        }
    }

// On Facebook login button
public void OnFacebook ()
    {
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions (perms, AuthCallback);
    }
```

Comment: yap, its working, but i have another doubt. in my reference video he's also not used  using Facebook.Unity;. their its worked correctly. here its not working. why?

Comment: May be he was using older sdk

Comment: i used this scripting, its not asking access token. it displays a message in console "This only needs to be called for iOS or Android" and "Using Facebook Unity SDK v7.3.0 with FBUnityEditorSDK/7.3.0"

Comment: Ignore this message

Comment: its not asking the access token

Comment: and in facebook settings its displays a message in Android Build Facebook Settings "OpenSSl not found. Make sure that OpenSSL is installed and that it is in your path". i already installed openSSL and i set the path also

Comment: OpenSSL required for finding Key Hash. You can get right Key Hash in logcat when you try to login in android device, it will show you the correct key hash, put that key hash into your facebook app (in developers.facebook)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34130/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-manoj-balaji-m).