# How solve 400 Bad Request error in unity?

Tags: unity

400 Bad Request
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
FBScript:DisplayUserName(IResult) (at Assets/Script/FBScript.cs:63)
Facebook.Unity.c__Iterator1:MoveNext() (at Assets/FacebookSDK/SDK/Scripts/Utils/AsyncRequestString.cs:133)

```
void DisplayUserName(IResult result){
    Text UserName = DialogUserName.GetComponent<Text>();
    if (result.Error==null  ) {
        UserName.text = "Hi there," + result.ResultDictionary ["first_name"];
    } else {
        Debug.Log (result.Error);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [SamedTarıkÇETİN](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/74040/samed-tar%C4%B1k-%C3%87et%C4%B0n) said,

> 400 Bad Request means "request is not valid", you can't get a valid response with an invalid request.

Thanks man.

Well, I hope you are following the general way to Login Facebook as described in [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114639/fb-init-is-not-accepting-in-my-c-script/114640#114640).

If you want to get User Name from Facebook then you can use Graph API in this way.

After login successfully, call Graph API for name as,

```
FB.API ("me?fields=name", HttpMethod.GET, GraphCallbackForName);
```

Then in `GraphCallbackForName` callback, retrieve name as,

```
void GraphCallbackForName (IGraphResult result)
{
    IDictionary<string,object> dict = result.ResultDictionary;
    string fbname = dict ["name"].ToString ();
    Debug.Log ("FB Name: " + fbname);
}
```

Comment: Although I respect the solution, you are wrong by saying "For 400 Bad Request you already got an answer". `400 Bad Request` means "request is not valid", you can't get a valid response with an invalid request.

Comment: @SamedTarıkÇETİN exactly man, I said you got answer, not you got **right** answer. I didn't even care about that. Anyways, you are right.

Comment: @Chetan There is one thing that only you can do, that is marking this as answer :P

Answer (score 0):

From [w3c.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1):

> 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

I assume you fetch the dictionary every frame, or so often. For fetching static information from websites, you shouldn't request so frequently.

And for a "username", it is enough to fetch at the Start method and store the info on a field.

So you don't have to fetch information again and again, you can just use the value of field.