# Why do I get this error with FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions?

Tags: unity, c#, facebook

I don't know what's wrong. I know that `FB.Login` is already deprecated. I don't know what syntax to use.

```
public class FBholder : MonoBehaviour {
    void Awake(){
        FB.Init (SetInit, OnHideUnity);
    }

    private void SetInit()
    {
        Debug.Log ("FB Init Done");

        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            Debug.Log ("FB Logged in");
        } else {
            FBlogin ();
        }
    }

    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {
        if (!isGameShown) {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        } else {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    void FBlogin()
    {
        FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions ("user_about_me, user_birthday", AuthCallback);
    }

    void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result)
    {
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
            Debug.Log ("FB Logged in worked");
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("FB Logged in failed");
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm getting this error

> Assets/FBholder.cs(40,6): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `Facebook.Unity.FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, Facebook.Unity.FacebookDelegate)' has some invalid arguments

and this

> Assets/FBholder.cs(40,35): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert`string' expression to type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114639/fb-init-is-not-accepting-in-my-c-script/114640#114640)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions), function LogInWithPublishPermissions has 2 arguments: IEnumerable permissions , FacebookDelegate callback. That's why your code dont compile.

If you took this code from tutorial, it maybe just outdated. Change according to FB API Documentation.